# How to show message after Backbone model was deleted?

Tags: backbone.js

I am using Backbone in my simple web application to manage collections and models.
Application has an event manager who listens for some of Backbone events and display proper messages. For example, when model was added to collection or edited I show message "Model was added" and "Model was edited".

But I have an issue when I delete model from collection. Backbone generates next events during deleting process:

1) request - event after "DELETE" request to server
2) destroy - model was deleted.
3) remove  - model was removed from all collections
4) sync    - model was synchronized

I have code like this one:

```
onSave: function () {
  console.log("Model was saved");
},

onRemove: function() {
  console.log("Model was removed");
}

Backbone.Notifications.on('sync',       this.onSave,            this);
Backbone.Notifications.on('remove',     this.onRemove,          this);
```

So when I delete model from collection I got 2 messages. First one is "Model was removed" and second one is "Model was saved". **How to prevent messages duplication or what code structure use to show messages to user for all CRUD operations ?** Thank you.

Comment: *"How to prevent messages duplication"* - I don't see the duplication you're referring to..?

Comment: `sync` handler shouldn't say *"Model was saved"*. Sync is  emitted for many operations. At least in this case it should say "Model got deleted from server"

Answer (score 0):

`sync` is called for any CRUD operation. When you destroy the model, the model is first removed from the collection, firing the onRemove handler, then `sync` is called to `DELETE` the model from the server, which fires the second event handler.

You could overload sync to listen to which CRUD operation is being performed and log this:

```
var sync = Backbone.prototype.sync;

Backbone.prototype.sync = function (method, item, options) {
  console.log('Method called was: ', method);
  sync.apply(item, arguments);
};
```

Comment: ... and hopefully this gets removed from production code

Answer (score 0):

One to do it would be to go the successhandler route:

```
model.destroy({
  success: function(){
    alert('Model deleted');
  }
});
```

This will only trigger when the server sends a 200 after the DELETE has been processed.